# How to Combine 2 Different Loops one is the name of the company the other the value? with python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

Hello Everybody can somebody help me, I'm trying to combine the result of 2 different loops in one data frame, my code is below: I will show the output and an idea of how I would like it, in advance I appreciate your help:

[image]

This my actual output

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

Thank you Guys Or also if there's any suggestion about my code or if I can make it simpler
I'm open to suggestions thank you all

Comment: hey, I gave an answer that I hope helps, in the future try to post you code as code in the text rather than as a screenshot, it makes it easier to copy over, test and edit

Comment: Can you confirm the url? I suspect there is a less complex solution at play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could zip the 2 lists (im assuming lists or tuples are returned for `soup.findall`) together and iterated over it once, and extract the 2 elements at the same time so you can pass that new list into a dataframe

```
prices_list=[]
for span1,span2 in zip(soup.findall("div", attr = {"class":"quote-rate-logo"}),soup.findall("span", attr = {"class":"quote-rate"}):
    for img in span1:
        #your code here
        image_name = foo
    prices = span.text
    prices_list.append([image_name, prices])
df = pd.DataFrame(prices_list)
```